# how to transfer different types of intents to another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to transfer from Main Activity to the Second Activity to intents: 
the first one is an empty intent that when I press a button it goes to the second activity.
The second one is when I write some text in the text view and it passes this text to the second activity. 
The problem is that it gives an error when I press the first button, but works fine when I pass the text. The code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnSoundBubble=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSoundBubble);
    Button btnSoundFrog=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSoundFrog);
    Button btnSend=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    btnSoundBubble.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSoundFrog.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);

    final ImageView iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
    iv.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.anima);
    iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AnimationDrawable anim= (AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground();
            anim.start();

        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnSoundBubble:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        MediaPlayer mpB=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.bubble);
        mpB.start();
        break;
    case R.id.btnSoundFrog:
        MediaPlayer mpF=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.frog_croaking);
        mpF.start();
        Intent intent1=new Intent(this,Third.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
        break;      
    case R.id.btnSend:
        String g;
        EditText editText1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        g=editText1.getText().toString();
        Intent intent2=new Intent(this,Second.class);
        intent2.putExtra("name", g);
        startActivity(intent2);
        break;
    }       
}
}
```

The Second Activity

```
public class Second extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    EditText editText2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    editText2.setText("You tapped: "+getIntent().getExtras().getString("name"));

    final ImageView imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.anima);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            AnimationDrawable anim=(AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
            anim.start();

        }
    });

    Button btnBack=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);  
}
}
```

The intent 1 (to the Third activity) works fine.

Comment: in the first button you are passing the intent first and then creating MediaPlayer object, this is wrong way, make it as you do in second button,(Change the sequence of code)
Because you lose current context when you pass an intent
make the first button code sequence as
1)create MediaPlayer Object
2)fire the intent

Answer (score 1):

Your code for Button 1:

```
case R.id.btnSoundBubble:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        MediaPlayer mpB=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.bubble);
        mpB.start();
        break;
```

You are creating an object of `MediaPlayer` after starting another activity. Which is not the right way of doing it.

What you can do:

1.)

```
   case R.id.btnSoundBubble:

  final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
   MediaPlayer mpB=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.bubble);
   mpB.start();
   }
  };
 handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 break;
```

2.)

```
case R.id.btnSoundBubble:
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
```

then in SecondActivity's `OnCreate`:

```
 MediaPlayer mpB=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.bubble);
        mpB.start();
```

Comment: Glad to help. Select my answer by clicking the tick in front of it. :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are not sending any data to second activity

```
 case R.id.btnSoundBubble:
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    MediaPlayer mpB=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.bubble);
    mpB.start();
    break;
```

but in this case you are sending data to second activity

```
case R.id.btnSend:
        String g;
        EditText editText1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        g=editText1.getText().toString();
        Intent intent2=new Intent(this,Second.class);
        intent2.putExtra("name", g);
        startActivity(intent2);
        break;
```

In Second activity you are always allowing to get the extras like this.

```
EditText editText2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    editText2.setText("You tapped: "+getIntent().getExtras().getString("name"));
```

Please provide some data in case1 i mention or perform some check like this.

```
if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
{
//do you code here..
}
```